# bad option error message while running script

Tags: unix

I have written a very simple script on my **UNIX OS (SunoS 5.10)** that is finding out file creation **time and date** and convert them to **integer** values. After converting them to integer values I concatenated my results. But when I run my script it error out saying:

> bad option -maxdepth

It even gives an error saying

> BAD OPTION -d

Are these commands not valid?

```
#!/bin/bash
  location=/u/abc/def

  file_CreationTime () {
  cd $location
  for entry in $(ls -r)
  do
  if [ "$entry" = "Ankur.txt" ];then
  filetime=$(find  "$entry" -maxdepth 0 -printf "%TH:%TM:%TS\n" | cut -c 1-8)
  timeConversion="${fileTime//':'}"
  filedate=$(find  "$entry" -maxdepth 0 -printf "%TY-%Tm-%Td\n")
  dateConversion=$(date -d "$filedate" +%Y%m%d)
  srfresult="$dateConversion$timeConversion"
  echo "$srfresult"
  fi;
  done

  }

 file_CreationTime
```

Comment: Please format your code with `{}`.

Comment: is it ok now? @codeforester

Comment: No, you can also see it!  I can assure you there will be very less chances of getting a good answer unless your question is readable.

Comment: hi my above code is working on LINUX OS .How can i find time and date in UNIX OS and convert them ti integer value. Please help!!!